How to automatically choose the "best" K for a STM model based on multiple diagnostic variables
In structural topic modeling using the stm R package, the function searchK allows the user to run multiple models with different numbers of topics, and then returns the diagnostic properties for each model, so that the user can choose which performed better and therefore choose the ideal number of topics (K) for the data.
Some of these measures are held-out likelihood (higher is better), residuals (lower is better), and semantic coherence (higher is better).
The data looks like this, where each row is a model with a different amount of topics (K):
# K   semcoh    heldout  residual
# 10 -55.25328 -5.584059 1.127426
# 15 -54.84985 -5.532205 1.07168
# 17 -57.78122 -5.516972 1.056486
# 20 -56.90894 -5.493265 1.030628
# 22 -58.15011  -5.44756 1.015333
# 25 -59.86378 -5.431342 1.003179

Using plot(), the package returns the following graphic which allows the user to choose the best model:

In this case, its cleat that 25 is the best amount of topics, because it has higher held-out likelihood and lower residuals.
But in cases like the following the decision is not so clear, as the higher held-out likelihood is around 17, but the residuals are not lower at K = 17, so it's kind of a tradeoff: after K = 17, the higher K is, the lower the residuals are (good), but the held-out likelihood decreases (bad), but the better measure in residuals is actually a smaller change than the worsening measure in held-out likelihood, therefore in this case it's not worth it to go for lower residuals. Is there a way to automate these kind of decisions?
In other words, is there a way to find the optimal value for a variable by looking at diminishing returns on different variables, i.e., choose considering the next possibility can measure better on one variable, but also worse on other variable, balance the win vs. the loss, and settle on a value?
I tried doing a median-based approach using the which functions, but it doesn't always give the best K:
median(c(
       which.max(results_a$semcoh),
       which.max(results_a$heldout),
       which.min(results_a$residual)
))


results_a <- structure(list(K = list(10, 15, 17, 20, 22, 25), semcoh = list(
    -55.2532813572245, -54.8498529671037, -57.7812176351009, 
    -56.9089355258198, -58.1501148277006, -59.8637782940342), 
    heldout = list(-5.58405885132492, -5.53220465315627, -5.51697205885505, 
        -5.49326482691615, -5.44755983789593, -5.43134154907285), 
    residual = list(1.12742587858013, 1.07167984608645, 1.05648599573627, 
        1.03062808239133, 1.01533334688186, 1.00317896181321)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")

results_b <- structure(list(K = list(10, 15, 17, 20, 22, 25), semcoh = list(
    -65.8929182884279, -69.437105852102, -73.1939358885751, -75.6839741459559, 
    -77.3398101594828, -77.3598106852508), heldout = list(-6.31404845126443, 
    -6.321083522624, -6.28269982323658, -6.30191607990617, -6.32046527332797, 
    -6.32299991122077), residual = list(1.34467069132499, 1.2780706228344, 
    1.23831374392626, 1.21041197190302, 1.19623018255656, 1.17377825556606)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")

